# Local Outlier Factor for high dimensional features

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, machine-learning, outliers, valueerror

I am trying to apply Local Outlier Factor algorithm to detect outliers into 29 features, using [scikit](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/auto_examples/neighbors/plot_lof.html) sample code, but the code was not working and I got this message:

```
    File "sklearn/neighbors/binary_tree.pxi", line 1294, in sklearn.neighbors.kd_tree.BinaryTree.query (sklearn/neighbors/kd_tree.c:11337)
    ValueError: query data dimension must match training data dimension
```

ValueError: query data dimension must match training data dimension

Note that I applied the same methodology on One class support vector machine, and I got the results.

```
    #--- import required libraries ---#
    import csv
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from sklearn import svm
    from sklearn.neighbors import LocalOutlierFactor
    #--- read csv file ---#
    with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        csv_values = list(reader)
    #--- convert data type from string to float ---#
    def read_lines():
        with open('test.csv', 'rU') as data:
            reader = csv.reader(data)
            for row in reader:
                yield [ float(i) for i in row ]
    #--- values for meshgrid  ---#
    xx, yy= np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-5, 5, 100), np.linspace(-5,5,100))
    #--- Classify observations into normal and outliers ---#
    X = []; X_train = []; X_test = []; X_outliers = []
    for i in range(len(csv_values)):
        if csv_values[i][-1] == '0':
            X.append(csv_values[i][:-1]) 
        else:
            X_outliers.append(csv_values[i][:-1])
    #--- convert lists to arrays ---#
    X=np.array(X)
    X_outliers1= np.array(X_outliers)
    #--- figure for all 29 plots ---#
    fig=plt.figure(1)
    for i in range(27):
        #--- select 2 columns each time ---#   
        X=X[:,i:i+2]
        X_outliers= X_outliers1[:,i:i+2]
        #--- classification ---#
        clf = LocalOutlierFactor(n_neighbors=20)
        y_pred = clf.fit_predict(X)
        y_pred_outliers = y_pred[998:]
        Z = clf._decision_function(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
        Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
        #--- plot settings ---#
        fig.add_subplot(9,3,i+1)
        fig.set_figheight(20)
        fig.set_figwidth(16)
        plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)
        plt.title("Local Outlier Factor (LOF)")
        plt.contourf(xx, yy, Z, cmap=plt.cm.Blues_r)
        a = plt.scatter(X[:998, 0], X[:998, 1], c='white')
        b = plt.scatter(X[998:, 0], X[998:, 1], c='red')
        plt.axis('tight')
        plt.xlim((-5, 5))
        plt.ylim((-5, 5))
        plt.legend([a, b],
                   ["normal observations",
                    "abnormal observations"],
                   loc="upper left")
            plt.savefig('test.png')
```

The csv file contains 1000 rows (data points) and 29 columns (features), one last column to classify normal from outliers. In this file 998 normal data points and 2 outliers.

Comment: Could you please trim down your code to only the section that is important and include some data? This way we could reproduce the error that you are getting and help you.